# Abrir URL Waze (maps) utilizando o webviewer Android

Tags: php

estou com uma dificuldade para abrir uma URL do Waze.

Atualmente estou criando uma pagina em HTML+PHP e utilizo o webviewer do Android para exibir a pagina, nela preciso colocar um link para chamar o Waze.

Se utilizo uma url simples:

```
<a href="waze://?q=rua%20don%20vilares,%2085" >waze</a>
```

ele me retorna um erro no webviewer:

> net::err_unknown_url_scheme

alguém sabe como posso resolver isso.

Answer (score 0):

Erro de `scheme` representa um erro com o prefixo da URL, com o que vem antes do endereço, propriamente dito, como `http:` `https:` `ftp:` `sftp`, etc.

Verifique o endereço que está passando. Não tenho certeza do padrão a ser usado, mas a url parece estranha.

Comment: esse formato que a api do waze informa, no navegador funciona normalmente, no webview não